# How to reset spinner back to default in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to display the collection of data based on the input being provided in the `AppCompatEditText`.

Please review the below screenshot

[image]

Based on the pincode, I would like to populate Localities, Districts and State. Here is the code snippet of what I have tried

```
 val districtsAdapter: ArrayAdapter<District> = ArrayAdapter(
                    applicationContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                )
                val localitiesAdapter: ArrayAdapter<Locality> = ArrayAdapter(
                    applicationContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                )
                val stateAdapter: ArrayAdapter<State> = ArrayAdapter(
                    applicationContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                )
                /* if (locationDetails.districts.isNotEmpty() && locationDetails.localities.isNotEmpty()) {*/
                enableLocationsBasedOnPincode(true)

                districtsAdapter.addAll(locationDetails.districts)
                districtsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                bindingSheet.district.adapter = districtsAdapter

                localitiesAdapter.addAll(locationDetails.localities)
                localitiesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                bindingSheet.locality.adapter = localitiesAdapter
                bindingSheet.locality.invalidate()
                if (locationDetails.state != null) {
                    stateAdapter.addAll(listOf(locationDetails.state))
                } else stateAdapter.addAll(listOf())
                localitiesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                bindingSheet.state.adapter = stateAdapter
```

If there are some locations available for the given pincode, the dropdown is getting being populated as below

[image]

If suppose I enter the `pincode` which does not have corresponding `localities/districts/states`, the **Spinner should be displayed as earlier but it is getting displayed in the following manner**.

[image]

How to make it displayed with default prompt like "Select District" / "Select Locality" / "Select State" instead of blank spaces?

The method implementation of `enableLocationsBasedOnPincode`:

```
 private fun enableLocationsBasedOnPincode(isEnabled: Boolean) {
        dialog.locality.isEnabled = isEnabled
        if (isEnabled)
            dialog.locality.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.all_edit_selector)
        else dialog.locality.background =
            resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.all_edit_txt_bg_disabled)
        dialog.district.isEnabled = isEnabled
        if (isEnabled)
            dialog.district.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.all_edit_selector)
        else dialog.district.background =
            resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.all_edit_txt_bg_disabled)
        dialog.state.isEnabled = isEnabled
        if (isEnabled)
            dialog.state.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.all_edit_selector)
        else dialog.state.background =
            resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.all_edit_txt_bg_disabled)

    }
```

Comment: You can add the prompts to the arraylist at index 0 and make it unselectable with a if statement , so it will always show the prompts in the blankspaces

Comment: But I want in the same views as earlier. I did not add such conditions at the beginning. The problem occurs once I have tried to reset the dropdown in Kotlin.

Comment: can you add code of `enableLocationsBasedOnPincode(true)` this method

Comment: @rahat  I have updated my post. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: I expected `enableLocationsBasedOnPincode` to have the code that does the mapping of pin code to city/district/area. can you add the code where you do mapping and change the spinner selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this this should work for spinners and edit texts, just change the "EditText" to the name of your view

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      EditTextName.setHint("Your Notes");
   }
  });
```

So when text changes in the field it makes a hint so if the data gets loaded into it it forces a hint, The problem is that when you enter an invalid pincode it loads blank information into the view, so the textwatcher above will trigger

Otherwise which is harder if someone enter an invalid pincode you give them a toast that says it is invalid and stops the data fromloading into the views, but that would involve having an array with all the valid pincodes